# Attempting to solve a system of linear equations, where one of my outputs is unknown but I do know it needs to be maximized

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, max

I have a set of linear equations that I am attempting to solve. I have five variables that are randomly assigned and sum to 1. I applied these variables row-wise to a matrix (i.e., Ax = B) However, the caveat is that one of my B variables needs to be maximized, subject to the constraint that the rest of my B variables are 0. My data is below:

```
import pandas as pd 

A =  [[0.031982, 0.02606, 0.055933, 0.004529, 0.064116],
     [-0.000167, 0.181031, 0.145465, 0.120430, 0.114093],
     [0.627812, 0.254377, 0.138211, 0.41156, -0.000801],
     [-0.228139, 0.377169, 0.085415, 0.008888, -0.020791],
    [-0.067697, -0.114113, 0.089583, 0.100222, -0.005291]]

B = [[maximized],
     [0],
     [0],
     [0],
     [0]]

x = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]
```

**Note**: 'maximized' is the value that I am attempting to maximize

What I've done so far:

```
import numpy as np

ABC=[]
A = DataFrame(A)
N=1000 #my attempt at maximizing by repeating the sequence N times and taking the largest value that results
for i in range(N):
     x = np.random.rand(5) #creating random variables
     x/= np.sum(x) #so that they sum to one
     x=x*A.T[0] #I apply the variables to my data. I want to maximize the sum of the first column, so I transpose and take a slice that I sum below
     x=x.sum()
     ABC.append(x)
ABC = DataFrame(ABC)
A2=ABC.sort_values(by=0,ascending=False).head(1) #I sort by largest first and take the highest value and store in a new dataframe
maximized=np.array(A2) #I convert the dataframe back into an array

B = [[maximized],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
X = np.linalg.inv(A).dot(B)
X
```

Obviously this has a lot of error and isn't really achieving what I want. What I want to do is to run a maximization function that gives me the largest value and input that value into my matrix. I don't really know where to go from here, or what sort of maximization function applies in this case. If anyone has any ideas, that would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a given matrix `A`. Then you want to find a positive vector `x` with sum 1 such that if `Ax = b` then `b` is the all-zeroes vector except that the first entry is maximized, rather than zero.

Let `A0` be the first row of matrix `A` and `Ar` be the rest. Then we can rephrase your problem as:

> Find vector `x` such that its entries are non-negative, sum to 1, where `Ar x = b`, `b = 0` and maximizing `A0 x`.

This is simply a standard linear programming instance (handling the 'sum-to-1' requirement by adding a single all-ones row to `Ar` and a `1` entry to `b`).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help :) I tried it this way and got an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a maximization problem I think.  There's only one answer with the specified result. If our maximized number is `c`, then `b = [[c,0,0,0,0]].T = c*[[1,0,0,0,0]].T`  Lets' set `b_` as `[[1,0,0,0,0]].T` so `b = c*b_`

If we solve `A @ x_ = b_` by `x_ = Ainv @ b_`, we get a single `x_` matrix that still needs to be normalized to form `x`.  If `len_x_ = np.linalg.norm(x_)`, then:

```
A @ (c * x_) = (c * b_)   # multiplying `c` though
A @ (c * x_) = b          # substituting `b = c * b_`
c * x_ = x = x_ / len_x_  # therefore . . . 
c = 1 / len_x_
```

`c` can only take one value if `A` is postive-definite, and thus `x` can only take one value:

```
b_ = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0]])
x_ = np.linalg.inv(A).dot(b_)
c = 1 / np.linalg.norm(x_)
b = b_ * c
x = x_ * c
```

Now, it'll get a *lot* more interesting if `A` isn't definite (i.e. it doesn't have an inverse).  But I'm not sure that's within scope, since you're currently solving by inverting `A`.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!